# What is the expectation value of number operator squared $\hat{N}^2$? I am confused with normal ordering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

### Definition of terms

\begin{align}
\hat{N} & = a^\dagger a, \\
a^\dagger|n\rangle & = \sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle, \\
a|n\rangle & = \sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle,
\end{align}

where $|n\rangle$ is the wavefunction of Fock state with $n$ photons.

$$a^\dagger a - a a^\dagger=1.$$

### The expectation value of $\hat{N}$

\begin{align}
\langle n|\hat{N}|n\rangle
& =\langle n|a^\dagger a|n\rangle
\\ & =\langle n|a^\dagger \sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle
\\ & =\langle n|\sqrt{n-1+1} \sqrt{n}|n-1+1\rangle
\\ & =n\langle n|n\rangle
\\ & =n
\end{align}

### The expectation value of $\hat{N}^2$

**Result 1** without normal ordering:

\begin{align}
\langle n|\hat{N}^2|n\rangle
& =\langle n|a^\dagger a a^\dagger a|n\rangle
\\ & =\langle n|a^\dagger a a^\dagger  \sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle
\\ & =\langle n|a^\dagger a\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n}|n\rangle
\\ & =n^2
\end{align}

**Result 2a** with normal ordering (for $n\geq2$):
\begin{align}
\langle n|\hat{N}^2|n\rangle
& =\langle n|a^\dagger a a^\dagger a|n\rangle
\\ & =\langle n|a^\dagger(1+a a^\dagger)a|n-1\rangle
\\ & =\langle n|a^\dagger a +a^\dagger a^\dagger a a|n\rangle
\\ & =n+\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n-1}\sqrt{n}
\\ & =n+n\sqrt{n^2-1}
\end{align}

**Result 2b** using $\langle n|a^\dagger a^\dagger a a|n\rangle=|aa|n\rangle|^2=n(n-1)$:
\begin{align}
\langle n|\hat{N}^2|n\rangle
& =\langle n|a^\dagger a a^\dagger a|n\rangle
\\ & =\langle n|a^\dagger(1+a a^\dagger)a|n-1\rangle
\\ & =\langle n|a^\dagger a +a^\dagger a^\dagger a a|n\rangle
\\ & =n+n(n-1)
\\ & =n^2
\end{align}

### The question

Result 1 and 2b are the same I am assuming correct result. What am I doing wrong in 2a?

Comment: check the $\sqrt{n}$ factors when you apply creation and annihilation operators

Comment: oh I see $a^\dagger |n-2>=\sqrt{n-1}|n-1>$ I went a bit too fast there thought it was acting on $|n-1>$

Comment: Please use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>` to typeset brakets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually in 2a there should be

\begin{align}
\langle n|a^\dagger a +a^\dagger a^\dagger a a|n\rangle
& =n+\langle n|a^\dagger a^\dagger \sqrt{n-1}\sqrt{n}|n-2\rangle
\\ & =\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n-1}\sqrt{n-1}\sqrt{n}
\\ & =n+n(n-1)
\end{align}

I had a feeling there was something more complicated about the powers of number operator but fortunately not.